# Catalyst development server appears to hang

Tags: catalyst

I am doing the usual operation of the inbuilt development server for my Catalyst app:

```
DBIC_TRACE=1 perl script/*_server.pl -d -r -p 3001 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/cat-dev.log
```

All runs nicely, and the server detects when files change and does a restart; then unpredictably it just locks up apparently. Browsing to the app on localhost:3001/ (and/or {local_IP}:3001/ over the LAN) freezes, with the browser saying 'loading...' or 'connecting...' in the case of a new connection.

This has been happening for a while and I have previously just thought "Oh well" and Ctrl-C'ed and re-run the server command. But this most recent time, I found the server process in htop and ran an strace on it. It was evidently quite busy, apparently checking the status of the source files to tell if it needed to restart. I then came over here to StackOverflow, read around for a bit, was about to post about this, went back to the browser and saw that it had now served up the page!

This was in the log file...

```
[debug] Rendering template "jobs_search_results.tt"
[debug] Response Code: 200; Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8; Content-Length: 74540
[info] Request took 963.465151s (0.001/s)
```

Co-workers have muttered about threads; a half related query on here suggested it might be related to database connection (I do connect to a remote DB); I have wondered about the '-r' activity... anything I should be looking for in this?

This is a recently updated Catalyst install.

Answer (score 1):

Id you suspect the restarter is causing some sort of weird block, try starting the server without it.

The basic server is single process, so it gets blocked easily.  try running your application with the forking option, that might clear it up as well